# Chaining reduce() with map() in JS

Tags: javascript

I've recently started JS from YouTube. I need help with some logic. I've an array of radius:

```
const radius = [3,1,2,4]
```

I want to calculate the diameter and also print the largest diameter. I tried:

```
const radius = [3, 1, 2, 4];

const myLogic = function (currentRadius) {
    return (2 * currentRadius)
}

const calculate = function (radius) {
    const output = [];
    radius.map(currentValue => output.push(myLogic(currentValue))).reduce((max, currentItem) => {
        if (max < currentItem) {
            max = currentItem;
        }
        console.log("Largest diameter: ",max);
    }, 0)
    return output;
}

console.log(calculate(radius));
```

Output:

```
1
undefined
undefined
undefined
[ 6, 2, 4, 8 ]
```

How can I get the largest Diameter. Please help.

Comment: `return max` at the end of the `reduce` method's callback function. You could also calculate the largest diameter without the `reduce()` method: `const calculate = function (radius) {
  const diameterArr = radius.map(myLogic);
  console.log('Largest diameter: ' + Math.max(...diameterArr));
  return diameterArr;
}`

Comment: `radius.map(myLogic).reduce(…)`…‽

Comment: You could also just do `return Math.max(...radius) * 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of minor issues. 1) you are not returning value in `map` function, thus the array is not having the values to be used for `reduce` call 2) in reduce method missing return on `max`

```js
const radius = [3, 1, 2, 4];

const myLogic = function (currentRadius) {
  return 2 * currentRadius;
};

const calculate = function (radius) {
  return radius.map(myLogic).reduce((max, currentItem) => {
    if (max < currentItem) {
      max = currentItem;
    }
    console.log("Largest diameter: ", max);
    return max;
  }, 0);
};

console.log(calculate(radius));

// calculate method further simplified into

const cal2 = (arr) =>
  radius.map(myLogic).reduce((max, curr) => (max < curr ? curr : max), 0);
  
  console.log('cal2-->', cal2(radius));
```

Comment: this answers my question. i realized my mistakes also..

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Math.max() method to get the largest number.

```
const radius = [3, 1, 2, 4];

const myLogic = function (currentRadius) {
    return (2 * currentRadius)
}

const calculate = function (radius) {
    radius = radius.map(currentValue => myLogic(currentValue));
    let max = Math.max(...radius);
    console.log(max);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is useful here:

```js
function double (num) {
  return num * 2;
}

function calculate (radii) {
  const diameters = [];
  let max = 0;

  for (const radius of radii) {
    const diameter = double(radius);
    diameters.push(diameter);
    if (diameter > max) max = diameter;
  }

  console.log(`Largest diameter: ${max}`);
  return diameters;
}

const radii = [3, 1, 2, 4];
console.log(calculate(radii));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    const arr = [5, 7, 8, 6, 3, 2, 1];

const radiusArr = arr.map((item) => item * 2)

const newArr = radiusArr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(newArr[newArr.length-1])


const large = radiusArr.reduce((preNumber, currNumber) => {
    if(preNumber > currNumber) {
        return preNumber
    } else {
        return currNumber
    }
})

console.log(large)
```